# DC Current Monitor (Datalogging)

Tags: monitoring

the basics:

Monitor DC Current over long hours (200hours)

Measure up to 8 channels simultaneously and log the data ready to plot on excel or graph after the testing duration.

Current from each channel will not exceed 1A. and voltage will be either 13.5V or 28V.

How could this be carried out?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There must be a better site for this question which has nothing to do with the Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to find, repourpus, or make your own measurement hardware, like this person did;
https://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/10/12/raspberry-pi-current-power-meter/